# merging a multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I tried my hardest to find a similar question but I wasn't 100% sure what exactly to search for.

The array below is from an e-commerce site I am creating.
Each item has colour variants with a unique item code, however items share a sku. I would like to merge the array by the sku code to calculate the quantity of each item. I have seen ways to merge arrays with the same key but can't find a way to merge these.

Thanks

```
array(4) {
  ["ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0002"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["itemcode"]=> string(16) "ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0002"
    ["sku"]=>string(8) "ITEM-CHAIR"
    ["quantity"]=>string(1) "4"
    ["price"]=>string(5) "49.99"
   }
 ["ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0003"]=>
 array(4) {
    ["itemcode"]=>string(16) "ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0003"
    ["sku"]=>string(8) "ITEM-CHAIR"
    ["quantity"]=>string(1) "7"
    ["price"]=>string(5) "49.99"
   }
 ["ITEM-KNIFE-v-V0001"]=>
 array(4) {
    ["itemcode"]=>string(22) "ITEM-KNIFE-v-V0001"
    ["sku"]=>string(14) "ITEM-KNIFE"
    ["quantity"]=>string(1) "1"
    ["price"]=>string(5) "45.00"
   }
 ["ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0001"]=>
 array(4) {
    ["itemcode"]=>string(16) "ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0001"
    ["sku"]=>string(8) "ITEM-CHAIR"
    ["quantity"]=>string(1) "4"
    ["price"]=>string(5) "49.99"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have tried iterating through the array and adding the quantity if the sku's match, I am struggling with the logic more than anything though, as what I have tried simply adds up the quantity of ALL the items in the basket, the end result I would like is to basically have an array which contains the sku as the key and the quantity as a value, for example from my array above, the key would be ITEM-CHAIR and the value would be 15 as there are 15 chairs in the basket, although they are a mixture of different variants.

Comment: If you provide code you have already, you get solution faster. You can also provide expected array. Just extend your question about this informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your array and just increment array with current counters if you found that key exist or create new index:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($inputArray as $item) {
    if (isset($results[$item['sku']])) {
        ++$results[$item['sku']];
    } else {
        $results[$item['sku']] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although this doesn't give me the exact thing I was after, which is the total quantity of each sku group, it has pointed me in the right direction so I will mark it as the correct answer. Sorry again if my question was vague.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand.

```
 $resultArray = [];
    foreach ($entryArray as $value){
        $resultArray[$value["sku"]][$value["itemcode"]]=$value;
    }
```

Now you get that:

```
array(2) {
    ["ITEM-CHAIR"]=>{
         array(3){
             ["ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0003"] => array(4){...}
             ["ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0002"] => array(4){...}
             ["ITEM-CHAIR-v-V0001"] => array(4){...}
         }
    }
    ["ITEM-KNIFE"]=>{
         array(1){
              ["ITEM-KNIFE-v-V0001"] => array(4){...}
         }     
    }
}
```

Maybe you want this.
So  you can use count($resultArray["ITEM-X"]) to get count of sku. And you also get a better sorted array of your products.